# when should we use sql cursor

Tags: t-sql

hi all tell me when should i use cursor?

thanks 
saj

Answer (score 7):

Ideally as little as possible. Cursors have quite a high inherent processing overhead

Either when

1. The process you are doing can not be rewritten as a set based operation. (For example [invoking DBCC DBREINDEX in turn](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/rebuilding_indexes_p1.aspx) on a list of tables)
2. The set based operation has worse asymptotic complexity. For running aggregates the set based solution has quadratic complexity whereas the cursor workload grows linearly.

For this last case using a [SQL CLR solution](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/running-sums-yet-again-sqlclr-saves-the-day.aspx) is significantly faster than using a standard cursor.

Answer (score 2):

Please read:
http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

You should be able to go your whole career without ever using a cursor unless you are a database admin.

Comment: While on principle I agree, I wouldn't say "whole career". Some times its just easier and faster to use a cursor than to find a way around them. If you can do it with a cursor in fifteen minutes instead of spending half a day for other alternatives, why wouldn't you? Of course providing that the cursor implementation is fast enough, but so far that has never been a problem for me.

Comment: @carlos, if you are familiar with the techniques described in the link, it is almost always faster to write the non-cursor solution. The code will be shorter, simpler, and easier to mainatin as well. Speed of development is only an excuse indicating you are not competent at SQL coding.

Comment: @HLGEM how about Cursor inside another Cursor? Can I the same thing without cursor so fast as I do with them?

Comment: @Mucida, a cursor within a cursor is even worse!! 90+% of all cursors can be avoided. The code to write using set-basd logic is usually faster to write once you understand how to do it. The performance imporvement is usually huge.

Comment: @HLGEM even a code with cursor inside cursor can be written using a set-based logic?

Comment: Of course. Depending on exactly what you are doing of course, but I have only rarely seen the actual need for a cursor (almost always things only a DBA should be doing). It is only that many devs don't think in sets and use SQl effectively. The set-based solution is almost alawys simpler and faster to implement and test too.

Comment: @HLGEM Can you update your answer to include the relevant parts of the website you linked that answer the question? I found this question on a google and the link is broken, so now your answer doesn't help much in its current state. :(

Comment: The link still works. I just went there. It is several pages long and all of it is relevant which is why I did not post what is in there.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a bit of info straight from Oracle:

QUICK GUIDE TO USING EXPLICIT CURSORS WITHIN SQL*FORMS 3.0
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Many users perceive Explicit Cursors as a difficult means of retrieving
data from the database.  In reality, only a few basic concepts are needed
to implement this flexible method, thus, maximizing efficiency and
developer control.

A cursor is a named SQL statement.  From the PL/SQL User's Guide and
Reference Manual (Page 2-16):

When a query returns multiple rows, you can explicitly define a cursor to:

- process beyond the first row returned by the query
- keep track of which row is currently being processed.

Cursors allow the designer precise control of the multiple values returned
by the cursor's SELECT statement.

Note that explicit cursors should be used in specific cases only.  For most
applications, the default database block is sufficient and easier to use
than explicit cursors.  Please read the last section of this document for
situations where explicit cursors may be appropriate.

Comment: Can you please link to the relevant documents and put the quoted text in a block so it's clear which part of the text is a quote and which is your own

Comment: Agreed - if you're going to quote official documentation, it is important to provide a link to the source, for both the purposes of further reading AND proper credit to the author.